# Mandrill: how to attach image as inline and as attachement?

Tags: php, mandrill

I am trying to attach an image which is in base64 format like

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j....

And I have following attachment code in php:

```
$attachment_encoded5 = $record['upload_file'];
                //$attachment_encoded5 = base64_encode($record['upload_file']);
                $attachment_array[] = 
                    array(
                        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
                        'name' => $record['name'].".jpeg",
                        'content' => $attachment_encoded5
                    );
```

So now what I am doing wrong here: 
- Do I need to convert dataurl image into base64?
- Do I need to use any other code to attach an image?
- Finally, how I can also attach an image as inline image?

Thanks in advance:) Please let me know as I am bit stuck:(

Answer (score 2):

Include images as inline attachments with your API calls using the `images` parameter. You'll need to provide the image name (Content-ID), the content (as a base64 encoded string), and the image MIME type. Reference the image name in the 'src' in your HTML content:

```
<img src="cid:image_name" />
```

[**`READ MORE`**](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582457-Tips-for-Using-Images-in-Mandrill-Emails)

so you need to wrap your existing array into another i.e `images`

```
function addInlineImage(){

   $image_name=$record['name'].".jpeg";

   $attachment=array(

    'images'=>

      array(
        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
        'name' => $image_name,
        'content' => $attachment_encoded5
      )

   );

  return [$attachment,$image_name];
}
```

You can return the image name and attachment from the function and use

```
list($attachment,$image_name)=addInlineImage();
```

and then use it in the tag as below

```
<img src="cid:<?=$image_name?>" />
```

just make sure the attachment you provide in the function `addInlineImages()` is `base64encoded`

For most SMTP libraries, including inline images is handled automatically. For example, if you insert an image inline, an img tag is added which then references the Content-ID of the image that's attached. How to add inline images will depend on the SMTP library being used.

Comment: thanks for quick answer so let me try it and do i need to provide img tag inside my template code or on php where I am passing email body message ?

Comment: try using the hardcoded name for the image and include that name in the tag and add it in the  `template` first.

Comment: hi I want solution dynamic and not the hardcodeed. As no use if I am attaching more than one image as inline and I am more looking into attach into body_message

Comment: Hi I tryed your code but sorry to say that it's not working for me:( can you provide an example of just attachment of image....not inline for now.

Comment: for a simple attachment refer [**`here`**](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.dart.html)

Comment: did you add the tag in the `HTML`? I know you dont want a hardcoded solution but first try it with hardcoded i did it a year back

Comment: Hey I have tried the hardcoded solution but that's not required by our project. Secondly, the simple attachment reference I already looked at many times and also implemented but not work. sorry that's why I was more looking into proper example